# Any Literature Related To Search of Counter Examples?

Tags: examples-counterexamples

I am looking for the well-summarized literature which holds any information about how to understand the overall logic related to searching of Counter examples.

I think,heuristically,this knowledge quite important and much more foundational because sometimes counterexamples save the tremendous time-wasting and also it helps to find the essence of the truth since counterexample is the complement of it.

However, by the mere search of my own, it reveals there's only context-specific counterexamples and its finding method. I want to look up some more holistic centralized logical picture of it.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Somebody told to me, that Maths is just a collection of counter-examples. Hence i agree with that motivation.